# multiple httpclient post call into foreach loop angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

This is my code

```
var resultmod = this.service.modulelist;      
resultmod.forEach(function (item) {
  if (item.visibility_flag == false) {
    /*delete visible flag */
    var pid = commonarray[0].permission_id;
    console.log(pid);
    this.service.deletemoduleval(pid, item.module_id).subscribe(res => {
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: and what is your problem / question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

The *specific* problem for you getting an error message here is that you are trying to call to the outer scope from inside a `function() { }`. `this` refers to the function itself. Instead you should use the arrow function syntax.

When you call `this.service`, the javascript is looking for a `service` property on the callback function.

```js
var resultmod = this.service.modulelist;      
resultmod.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.visibility_flag == false) {
    /*delete visible flag */
    var pid = commonarray[0].permission_id;
    console.log(pid);
    this.service.deletemoduleval(pid, item.module_id).subscribe(res => {
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply.I change for each to for loop problem solved

Comment: You can also solve it by changing it to a loop. Did you also try my method? Have you taken the time to understand *why* you were getting the problem, and why my fix for that works?